# Using pandas.qcut while taking into account a column Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

And using the pandas.qcut function I'm trying to make a new column that cuts by Animal by a factor of 3 like so:

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
    import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Harry','Sally','Mary','John','Francis','Devon','James','Holly','Molly','Nancy','Ben'], 'Score': [43,234,54,34,12,43,54,65,23,12,32],
                 'Animal': ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'dog', 'snake', 'dog', 'mouse', 'horse']})
tiles = pd.qcut(df.index, 3, labels=False)
tiles=tiles+1
df['tiles']=tiles
print(df)
```

How do I make my qcut function take into my account my 'Animal' column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if `qcut` is the way to go, but you can do this using `groupby('Animal').cumcount`, and taking the modulus of the cumulative count and 3 (`% 3`):

```
>>> df
   Animal     Name
0     cat    Harry
1     cat    Sally
2     cat     Mary
3     dog     John
4     dog  Francis
5     dog    Devon
6     dog    James
7   horse    Holly
8   mouse    Molly
9   mouse    Nancy
10  snake      Ben

df['Tile'] = (df.groupby('Animal').cumcount()%3)+1

>>> df
   Animal     Name  Tile
0     cat    Harry     1
1     cat    Sally     2
2     cat     Mary     3
3     dog     John     1
4     dog  Francis     2
5     dog    Devon     3
6     dog    James     1
7   horse    Holly     1
8   mouse    Molly     1
9   mouse    Nancy     2
10  snake      Ben     1
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to success is a proper function generating `Tile` values:

```
def tbl(x):
    ccl = itertools.cycle([1,2,3])
    lst = [ next(ccl) for _ in range(len(x)) ]
    return pd.Series(lst, x.index)
```

It works almost like `cumcount()` with one difference: Instead of consecutive
numbers (from `range`) it generates a cycled sequence of `[1,2,3]`,
using `itertools.cycle`.

Then all you have to do (after necessary imports and creation of the source
DataFrame) is:

- Sort values by `Animal`.
- Group by `Animal`, take any column (e.g. `Name`) and apply to them
  the above mentioned function.

So the whole script (without `tbl` declaration) can be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame( {'Name': ['Harry', 'Sally', 'Mary', 'John', 'Francis',
        'Devon', 'James', 'Holly', 'Molly', 'Nancy', 'Ben'],
    'Score': [43, 234, 54, 34, 12, 43, 54, 65, 23, 12, 32],
    'Animal': ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'horse', 'dog', 'snake',
        'cat', 'mouse', 'mouse']})
df.sort_values(by='Animal', inplace=True)
df['Tile'] = df.groupby('Animal')['Name'].apply(tbl)
```

When you print `df`, the result is:

```
       Name  Score Animal  Tile
2      Mary     54    cat     1
3      John     34    cat     2
8     Molly     23    cat     3
0     Harry     43    dog     1
1     Sally    234    dog     2
4   Francis     12    dog     3
6     James     54    dog     1
5     Devon     43  horse     1
9     Nancy     12  mouse     1
10      Ben     32  mouse     2
7     Holly     65  snake     1
```